# How do you find by a sub-document reference using mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to search off the contents of a sub-document referenced by ObjectId, like so:

```
Model.Idea.findOne('_key.code':code).populate('_key').exec (err,idea) ->
  return done err if err
  should.exist idea
```

The schema looks like this:

```
Key = new mongoose.Schema(
  type:
    type: String
    enum: types
    index: true
  code:
    type: String
    index:
      unique: true
)
Model.Key = ...

Idea = new mongoose.Schema(
  text: String
  name: String
  _key:
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: 'Key'
)
Model.Idea = ...
```

The reason that I'm doing it like this is that I want to pre-allocate a bunch of keys across a variety of key types and then allocated them out as needed.

For some reason I thought this was possible but the query doesn't seem to be returning any results. Is there a way to do it without looking up the key first and then referencing the Id? I think I may have got the impression you can do this from embedded subdocuments though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  Your `Idea.findOne` query selector cannot refer to properties within `_key` because its population doesn't occur until after the main query completes.

Comment: Yup, and even if it could magic the data out of thin air it would be doing a load of invisible work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Model.Idea.findOne()
.populate('_key', null, {'code':code})
.exec (err,idea) ->
  return done err if err
  should.exist idea
```

Comment: That won't quite do it.  It would get the first `Idea` document from the collection and then populate the `_key` field only it satisfies the `{'code':code}` condition.

Comment: Yeah and presumably the alternative would be fetching all of the ideas `Model.Idea.find().populate('_key',null,{'code',code}).exec(...)`, poulating '_key' on matching documents, which is quickly untractable. This question was wishful thinking on my part.